# Await does not seem to wait in safari js

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

Experimenting with the following code to automatically skip intros on netflix. This works perfectly as a chrome extension, but as a safari extension, it doesn't seem to actually wait 80000. Instead, it immediately entres the next loop, so then we are left with a page that continuously clicks on the button (as the button does not immediately disappears).

How could I actually make safari wait / sleep? Thanks!

```
'use strict';

console.log("NASI loaded.");

// prereq functions
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
};

async function check() {
while(true) {
  while(document.getElementsByClassName("skip-credits").length == 0) {
    await sleep(1000);
  }

  await sleep(1000);
  if($(".skip-credits")[0])
    $(".skip-credits")[0].children[0].click();

  console.log("Skipped.");
  await(80000);
}
};

check();
```

Comment: You're calling `await(80000);` instead of `await sleep(80000);` That looks like a typo.

Comment: omg you're right. I feel like an idiot. Thanks @MarkMeyer

Comment: Sometimes fresh eyes help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy fix, typo. Need to do

```
await sleep(80000);
```

Thanks @Mark Meyer.

Comment: Typo questions should just be closed, no need to answer.